# Cannot download file using fpassthru?

Tags: php

I have scripted a download file on **PHP**. I use **fpassthru** but I cannot download any file. It just print binary code on my page. When I tried uploading it on host and it works fine.

Can anyone explain why my PHP file is not working on local? 
Note: I am using **XAMPP** on **Mac**.

Here is my code:

```
$filename = $data['PathFile'];
$directory = '../upload/'.$filename;
if (file_exists($directory) && is_readable($directory)) {
   $size = filesize($directory);
   header('Content-Type: application/octet-stream');
   header('Content-Length: '.$size);
   header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename='.$filename);
  header('Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary');
  $file = @ fopen($directory, 'rb');
  if ($file) {
     fpassthru($file);exit;
  }
```

Comment: Please check your headers with development console (built in any browser you use). The `Content-Disposition` is explicitly telling the browser that file should be downloaded, so, i guess, it somehow got lost on the way to browser. P.S. and don't forget to wrap filename in double quotes - otherwise any space in file name will break your script.

Comment: Remove Run code snippet button as there no actual code snippet to run

Comment: Dont use [at] shutup operator. It is a bad practice.

Comment: I'd recommend [`readfile()`](http://php.net/manual/function.readfile.php) over `fpassthru` for this

Answer (score 0):

Please Check your Directory or path. Giving an example of another code for download please try this.

```
$file = 'Pareshaan.mp4';
if (file_exists($file)) {
    header('Content-Description: File Transfer');
    header('Content-Type: application/octet-stream');
    header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="'.basename($file).'"');
    header('Expires: 0');
    header('Cache-Control: must-revalidate');
    header('Pragma: public');
    header('Content-Length: ' . filesize($file));
    readfile($file);
    exit;
}
```